# How to know if I am in a screen of a screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I know how to see if I am in a screen: I have made an alias `alias inscreen = 'echo $STY'` .

But earlier today, I accidently type `screen` inside a `screen` without noticing it and in some way it made me make a mistake later.

---

Things I've observe when I type `screen` (inner screen) inside a `screen` (outer screen):

1. `screen -ls` only shows 1 result related to that screen
2. `echo $STY` is the same in both inner and outer screen
3. `ctrl + A` and `ctrl + D` can detach from the inner screen to no screen, but when `screen -r` back, both inner screen and out screen exist
4. now I can `exit` twice: inner screen `exit` -> outer screen `exit`

**So my question is**, is there anyway I could know I am in a screen of a screen?

---

P.S. When type `screen` for the first time, it will pop some text:

[image]

if type `screen` inside a `screen`, it won't show these hints.

Comment: Well I just think of a possible solution, when I `exit` a screen, then `screen -ls`, if it shows any screen is `attached`, that mean I was exited from an inner screen just now.

Comment: The default for `screen` when run within an existing `screen` session is to create a new window in that session. Are you running `screen -m`, or just mistaking a window for a new session? If you don't have a status line configured, maybe set one that shows window details (e.g., `hardstatus string '%?%-Lw%?(%n*%f %t%?(%u)%?)'`) and see if you aren't just seeing windows in action.

Comment: @muru ya someone just told me that when I type `screen` inside a screen, it opens something called "window", not a nested screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @geirha, a bash guru from libra irc #bash:

> if you run  ''screen''  inside a screen, you open a new window in that screen. It does not start a nested screen.

so typing `screen` inside a screen, I am opening new windows.

> you can switch between the windows with `ctrl+a n` and `ctrl+a p`

> also, try   ctrl+a :`caption always`

this would show a status bar indicating which window you are current in.

---

Also:

> put    `caption always "%{ Mk}%-w%{ Wk}%n %t%{ Mk}%+w"`     in `~/.screenrc`

would have a cool status bar every time you enter `screen`:

[image]

(Format specifiers customizing how the caption will look. See STRING ESCAPES in man screen)

> Ctrl+a :`title "hello world"`

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Title-Command